# map.get($foo, bar) is flagged with "semi-colon expectedscss(css-semicolonexpected)"

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I am getting linting error when trying to use SCSS maps, specifically  `map.get()`.

I am currently using the "stylelint" extension for Visual Studio Code in combination with Create React App build environment.

`map.get($foo, bar);`

stylint is returning an error for the `.` between `map` and `get()`

Error: semi-colon expectedscss(css-semicolonexpected)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but changing `.` to `-` didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the documentation for SASS maps again i noticed there is an alternate syntax:

`map-get($map, $key)`

Using `-` instead of `.` seams to appease the linter.